# Implementar patron para un método con acciones parecidas en dos clases diferentes

Tags: java, android, programación-móvil

tal vez no es muy claro el titulo pero bueno are la explicación.
Lo estoy programando en java para android.

Tengo dos clases(Son Activitys) las cuales las dos utilizan la clase SoundPool cada clase tiene su propia instancia de la clase SoundPool.

Las clases se llaman Calibracion y Test.

Para la clase Calibracion cree un metodo publico que hace lo siguiente.

```
public void pausasonido(){
    this.aprovadopaso2.setImageResource(R.drawable.reprovado);
    this.textopaso2.setText("2: Cargando Sonido.... Espera");
    this.sonido.autoPause();
    this.reproduciendo = false;
}
```

Para la clase Test cree un metodo publico que hace lo siguiente.

```
public void pausasonido(){
    this.sonido.autoPause();

}
```

La explicacion de por que son públicos estos métodos es la siguiente.

Tengo otra clase llamada **ListenerAuriculares** esta clase lo que hace es estar pendiente que los auriculares estén conectados o no. Su código se vería asi.

```
public class ListenerAuriculares  extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static ListenerAuriculares instancia;
private static String TAG = "Main";
private AppCompatActivity actividad ;
private boolean desconectados =true;



private  ListenerAuriculares(){

}


/**
 * Metoo para implementar patron singleton
 * @return retorna la instanacia e esta clase
 */
public static ListenerAuriculares getInstancia(){
    if(instancia == null){
        instancia = new ListenerAuriculares();
        return instancia;
    }else{
        return  instancia;
    }
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)){
        //Estado de los audifonos 1 para conectado 0 para desconectados
        int estado = intent.getIntExtra("state",-1);

        Button saliddetodo = null;
        switch (estado){
            case 1:
                Log.i(TAG, "Conectados");
                this.desconectados =false;

                //Verificacion segun la activity que me enviaron reproducir el sonido
                if("CalibracionActivity".equals(this.TAG)){
                    Calibracion activdad = (Calibracion)this.actividad;
                    activdad.resumesonido(1,0);
                }else if("Test1Activity".equals(this.TAG)){
                    Test1 actividad = (Test1)this.actividad;
                    actividad.resumesonido(1,0);
                }

                break;
            case 0:

              //Verificacion segun la activity que me enviaron pausar el sonido
                if("CalibracionActivity".equals(this.TAG)){
                    Calibracion activdad = (Calibracion)this.actividad;
                    activdad.pausasonido();
                }else if("Test1Activity".equals(this.TAG)){
                    Test1 actividad = (Test1)this.actividad;
                    actividad.pausasonido();
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Desconectados");
                break;
            default:
                this.desconectados =true;
                Log.i(TAG, "Desconocido Default");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

*Ahora lo que tiene que hacer esta clase es parar el sonido* **que en caso de que se desconecten los auriculares**, pero como se pueden dar cuenta ahora la clase esta funcionando pero quiero saber si se puede hacer mas dinámico el código.

Como se ve en el codigo a la clase Listener hay dos atributos que le paso un AppCompatActivity y un tag TAG.  Para que esta clase sepa con cual de las dos clases(Test, Calibracion) esta trabajando.

Lo que quiero llegar hacer, es evitar la utilizacion del siguiente fragmento de codigo en la clase.

```
if("CalibracionActivity".equals(this.TAG)){
                    Calibracion activdad = (Calibracion)this.actividad;
                    activdad.pausasonido();
                }else if("Test1Activity".equals(this.TAG)){
                    Test1 actividad = (Test1)this.actividad;
                    actividad.pausasonido();
                }
```

*Como se evidencia me es necesario hace un equals al tag para que la clase sepa con que activity esta trabajando. Y quiero evitar eso para cuando yo quiera agregar otra clase no tenga que añadir código a la clase Listener.
Gracias*

Comment: yo soy muy nuevo en java, pero una clase abstracta no te serviría, por los métodos parecidos? Además adaptar la clase con callbacks mediante una interfaz

Comment: Que quieres lograr? Que depende que tipo de clase llamo al metodo se ejecute pero sin una condicion que lo evalue?

Comment: @sioesi Lo que quiero lograr es que la clase listener controle el flujo de reproducción del sonido.

Comment: @FuriosoJack puedes poner de que clase es sonido? En ambas clases?

Comment: @sioesi sonido simplemente es un atributo de una instancia de la clase SoundPool, dicho atributo lo tiene tanto Test, como Calibracion.

Comment: @sioesi Ahora realmente lo que se me acabo de ocurrir no instanciar la clase SoundPool en los activitys sino dejarle ese trabajo a la clase Listener para que sea mas fácil de manejar el flujo de sonido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo haria en tu caso es una clase que se encargue solo de controlar el sonido

```
public class Sonido {
     public SoundPool sonido;

     //getters and setters

     public void pauseSonido(){
            this.sonido.autoPause();
     }
}
```

Mientras que cuando necesites ejecutar este metodo mas otro codigo simplemente verificas de donde se esta llamando

```
Sonido sonido = new Sonido();
sonido.pauseSonido();
if ( context instanceof Calibracion ) {
    this.aprovadopaso2.setImageResource(R.drawable.reprovado);
    this.textopaso2.setText("2: Cargando Sonido.... Espera");
    this.reproduciendo = false;
 }
```